# Java Error -> Actual and Formal argument / IContext / Recompile with -Xlint

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors, argument-passing

OKay, I'm not new to java but my knowledge of java has always been relatively basic. I am currently working on a different software that references java codes and the project I'm doing is on the outdated version of the project. SO when I try to migrate my project from the outdated version to the new updated version, it attempts to compile the java codes and comes out with two errors, mostly on;

```
FriendlyURLS fu = new FriendlyURLS();
required: IContext
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

        Buildfile: C:\Mendix_Proj\LV Broker Portal-branch_newMendixMigration_11Sept\deployment\build_core.xml
    compile-legacy:
    [javac] Compiling 846 source files to C:\Mendix_Proj\LV Broker Portal-branch_newMendixMigration_11Sept\deployment\run\bin
    [javac] C:\Mendix_Proj\LV Broker Portal-branch_newMendixMigration_11Sept\javasource\contentmanagement\actions\AddTemporarySEFRequestHandler.java:35: error: constructor FriendlyURLs in class FriendlyURLs cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]         FriendlyURLs fu = new FriendlyURLs();
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac]   required: IContext
    [javac]   found: no arguments
    [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    [javac] C:\Mendix_Proj\LV Broker Portal-branch_newMendixMigration_11Sept\javasource\ipsecurity\helpers\IPRangeCheckerLoginAction.java:32: error: constructor UserAction in class UserAction<R> cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]     {
    [javac]     ^
    [javac]   required: IContext
    [javac]   found: no arguments
    [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    [javac]   where R is a type-variable:
    [javac]     R extends Object declared in class UserAction
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 2 errors
    BUILD FAILED
    C:\Mendix_Proj\LV Broker Portal-branch_newMendixMigration_11Sept\deployment\build_core.xml:48:
    Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated!!! (Sorry for the long message)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `FriendlyURLs` class requires an argument of type `IContext` in its constructor. Check the FriendlyURLs.java file for this, and try understanding where is the missing argument.

Comment: I've got the java file open in front of me. The IContext Is present, but still doesn't explain it's use nor how it affects the class involved.
That said, I'm going to try it out and see what error/success that gives me.

Comment: public class FriendlyURLs extends CustomJavaAction<Boolean>
{
 public FriendlyURLs(IContext context)
 {
  super(context);
 }

Comment: in `AddTemporarySEFRequestHandler.java` send an instance of the `IContext` to the constructor. Should be something like `FriendlyURLs fu = new FriendlyURLs(myContext);`

Comment: (myContext); + fu.IContext(myContext); brings up an [[cannot find symbol]]error. I tried (context) to see, and that gave me a private access in CoreAction error. I know I am missing something. It's just hard to pinpoint.

Comment: Try looking for a class that implements IContext, and see if you have an instance of it.